# Understanding a Mysql Query from mysql reference manual

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to learn mysql from their reference manual. Here's an example table.

```
MariaDB [menagerio]> select * from shop; 
+---------+--------+-------+             
| article | dealer | price |             
+---------+--------+-------+             
|    0001 | A      |  3.45 |             
|    0001 | B      |  3.99 |             
|    0002 | A      | 10.99 |             
|    0003 | B      |  1.45 |             
|    0003 | C      |  1.69 |             
|    0003 | D      |  1.25 |             
|    0004 | D      | 19.95 |             
+---------+--------+-------+             
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And a query like this.

```
MariaDB [menagerio]> select s1.article s1aritle, s1.dealer s1dealer, 
s1.price s1price, s2.article s2article, s2.dealer s2dealer, s2.price 
s2price from shop s1 
left join shop s2 on s1.price < s2.price where s2.article is not null; 
+----------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+ 
| s1aritle | s1dealer | s1price | s2article | s2dealer | s2price | 
+----------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+ 
|     0003 | B        |    1.45 |      0001 | A        |    3.45 | 
|     0003 | C        |    1.69 |      0001 | A        |    3.45 | 
|     0003 | D        |    1.25 |      0001 | A        |    3.45 | 
|     0001 | A        |    3.45 |      0001 | B        |    3.99 | 
|     0003 | B        |    1.45 |      0001 | B        |    3.99 | 
|     0003 | C        |    1.69 |      0001 | B        |    3.99 | 
|     0003 | D        |    1.25 |      0001 | B        |    3.99 | 
|     0001 | A        |    3.45 |      0002 | A        |   10.99 | 
|     0001 | B        |    3.99 |      0002 | A        |   10.99 | 
|     0003 | B        |    1.45 |      0002 | A        |   10.99 | 
|     0003 | C        |    1.69 |      0002 | A        |   10.99 | 
|     0003 | D        |    1.25 |      0002 | A        |   10.99 | 
|     0003 | D        |    1.25 |      0003 | B        |    1.45 | 
|     0003 | B        |    1.45 |      0003 | C        |    1.69 | 
|     0003 | D        |    1.25 |      0003 | C        |    1.69 | 
|     0001 | A        |    3.45 |      0004 | D        |   19.95 | 
|     0001 | B        |    3.99 |      0004 | D        |   19.95 | 
|     0002 | A        |   10.99 |      0004 | D        |   19.95 | 
|     0003 | B        |    1.45 |      0004 | D        |   19.95 | 
|     0003 | C        |    1.69 |      0004 | D        |   19.95 | 
|     0003 | D        |    1.25 |      0004 | D        |   19.95 | 
+----------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
```

My question is I was trying to join the shop table with itself comparing their price but I couldn't get why this table results 21 row when I've had 7 row in the main table & what's actually happening here. Can anyone please help me understand this ?

Comment: Can you add your required output as text to the question?

Comment: You have 6 prices < 19.95 ,3 < 3.45 - it soon adds up

Comment: thanks @P.Salmon. Can you please just simply explain how that query resulted 21 rows from 7 when i tried to join the same table with itself ? I acutally wanted to know what happened behind the scene ..

Comment: You maybe need to get your head around join types Here's a reference wtih pictures https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/joins.php found by googling mysql joins or sql joins https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a join of all the elements on first table (shop) with only the elements of the second table (shop again) that have the price bigger than the first element, and their code it´s not null (you don´t need this because there is no article with null code) so:

The article code 0001 and dealer A tryes to make relation with all the rest :

1. With itself does not match because the price it´s equal (it sgould be less)
2. With 0001 and dealer B matches because the price it´s lower, so makes a row
3. With 0002 and dealer A matches because price is lower and makes a row
4. With 0003 and dealer B doesn´t mathc because price is higher. Does not make a row
5. With 0003 and dealers C and D it´s the same as number 4
6. For article 0004 and dealer D, as the price is lower, it makes a row.

Now you have to do the same for all the rest of the  articles to see if they match or not.

**EDIT**

For your first row:

0003 | B        |    1.45 |      0001 | A        |    3.45

The article 0003, dealer B and price 1.45 matches with the article 0001, dealer A and price 3.45 because the price of first element (1.45) is lower than the price of the second (3.45) and the article id of the second element (0001) is not null

**NEW EDIT**

Why this one is the first row?? Because you are not using ORDER BY. In SQL, if you don´t use ORDER BY, the order of the  result set is unpredictable, so the first row you get is the first row the system founds that matches the condition. This order depends on several factors (how many insert and delete you have done, what you have done before, what blocks of the file it has in memory, the indexes you have made, etc). If you need the result in a order, you must use ORDER BY

Comment: thanks @nacho, can you please just explain this first row of the result I think it'll be enough for me to understand.

Comment: No `s2.article` will ever be NULL because it's used in the join-condition.

Comment: thanks @nacho for your reply, but for my bad, I actually asked why this has be the first row why else's are not.

Comment: @nacho great :)

Answer (score 1):

See the rightmost column ,it contains all values of price.
Basically what happens here is
The row with the lowest price in Table will be matched with every other row in the table. The row with the highest price will not be matched with any other rows.

So your output is correct according to your query

If this is not ok ,then use equi-join

```
select s1.article s1aritle, s1.dealer s1dealer, 
       s1.price s1price, s2.article s2article, s2.dealer s2dealer, s2.price 
       s2price 
from shop s1 
     left join shop s2 on s1.article=s2.article
where s1.price < s2.price and s2.article is not null;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but that query was ok I just wanted to know why and how this query resulted this. @Kedar Limaye

Comment: See the edited answer,i have kept my query as it is but explanation at the top

Answer (score 0):

`on s1.price < s2.price` will count like `6 + 5 + 3 + 2 + 1`

1. There are 6 row match on `s2` table,when `s1.price = 1.25`.
2. There are 5 row match on `s2` table,when `s1.price = 1.45`.
3. There are 4 row match on `s2` table,when `s1.price = 1.69`.
4. There are 3 row match on `s2` table,when `s1.price = 3.45`.
5. There are 2 row match on `s2` table,when `s1.price = 3.99`.
6. There are 1 row match on `s2` table,when `s1.price = 10.99`.

You can add `order by s1.price` on your query command will eazy to know that.

```
select s1.article s1aritle, s1.dealer s1dealer, 
s1.price s1price, s2.article s2article, s2.dealer s2dealer, s2.price 
s2price 
from shop s1 
left join shop s2 on s1.price < s2.price 
where s2.article is not null
ORDER BY s1.price
```

you can see my another demo sample

Here is another sample

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd04480/4*

Answer (score 0):

A stupid query like this should not be found in the offifial reference manual.

#1: The join condition `s1.article=s2.article` is probably missing, otherwise you get an exploding result set close to a CROSS JOIN. When there are no duplicate prices you'll compare every row with every other row with a lower price and get `n*(n-1)/2` rows in your result set: `n=7: 7*6/2=21`. And for `n=1000: 1000*999/2=499500`

#2: The `Left Join` is not needed at all, because the `where s2.article is not null` turns it into an Inner Join anyway.

The intended query is probably:

```
select s1.article AS s1aritle,
   s1.dealer AS s1dealer, 
   s1.price AS s1price,
   s2.article AS s2article,
   s2.dealer AS s2dealer,
   s2.price AS s2price
from shop s1 
join shop s2
  on s1.article=s2.article
 and s1.price < s2.price;
```

and then it returns all articles which are sold in multiple shops and compares them to the shops with higher prices (excluding the shop with the highest price).

Comment: com'n @dnoeth, It's not an exact copy from the manuel, i'm trying to learn from it. and so i changed the query a bit.

Comment: @AmiNirob: You should know in advance what you're trying to achieve :-) This query is quite useless (as almost any query without equi-joins, i.e. joins based on equality). SQL allows you to do any kind of dumb things as long as the syntax is correct